# JQuery fadeIn( ) not working - simple example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've read the docs, but I can't get to the bottom why this example doesn't fade in the div:

`$('#application-name-label').fadeIn('slow');`

It's a unique id, but the element is just there from the loading of the page, doesn't fade in.

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/GBjxH/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you put:

```
 #application-name-label {
     display: none;
 }
```

?

Comment: @Federico Piragua I didn't. Didn't know I had to. Thank you.

Comment: But you had that in your Fiddle D:

Comment: Thanks! What a pain

Answer (score 3):

It fades in just fine. If your computer is too slow to load the page, you might not be able to see it. Try `.fadeIn(5000)` or something.

Comment: Side note:  I tested in IE 10, Chrome and FF latest and safari.  All worked just fine